# Disable error handling for mocha.js

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

Does anyone know if there a way to disable error handling by Mocha?

I'd really like to let the exception bubble up and be handled by the browser during debugging.

Update:
The context is this. 
- Some code throw's an unexpected error. 
- I would like to disable "try/catch" (something like jasmine's tests do) and be thrown into the debugger in chrome.

This way I can inspect the current state of the application at that moment.
It sounds like there isn't something built in, and I will need to manually do this each time I get some odd error in a test. Maybe by wrapping my code with

```
try {
  somethingThatBreaks();
} catch(e) {
  debugger;
}
```

Comment: If you explained the context which calls for disabling Mocha's exception handling, you might avoid the downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Mocha installs its own `onerror` handler to trap exceptions that may occur in asynchronous code. You can disable it with:

```
window.onerror = undefined;
```

This is **dangerous**. You should do this only when you must absolutely do so. If you make this a routine thing, Mocha will completely miss errors that happen in asynchronous code.

If what you want to do is let exceptions in *synchronous* code bubble up, I'm not seeing what this would accomplish. If you want to *inspect* the exception before Mocha touches it, a `try...catch` block wrapping your test will do this.

Answer (score 0):

Mocha's error handling is contained in the following [code](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/blob/master/lib/runnable.js#L210):

```
if (this.async) {
  try {
    this.fn.call(ctx, function(err){
      if (err instanceof Error || toString.call(err) === "[object Error]") return done(err);
      if (null != err) return done(new Error('done() invoked with non-Error: ' + err));
      done();
    });
  } catch (err) {
    done(err);
  }
  return;
}

// sync
try {
  if (!this.pending) this.fn.call(ctx);
  this.duration = new Date - start;
  fn();
} catch (err) {
  fn(err);
}
```

You could possibly throw the error with the catch (or remove the `try..catch` entirely) however it would most likely break the test suite if a test fails.

Answer (score 0):

`mocha.options.allowUncaught=true`
But in this case, the rest of the tests will break if the error is not caught within mocha. Disabling `try{} catch(){}` in mocha will only be useful when debugging.

To create a test, I suggest using the construction

(for browser)

```js
try{
   throw new Error()
} catch (e){
   // Let's say it's called in a yor error listeners.
   e.handler=()=>{
      done(e)
   }
   let event= new ErrorEvent('error',{error:e})
   window.dispatchEvent(event);
   
}
```